# Load txt and convert to npy keeping the same shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, load, numpy-ndarray

I have a [.txt file](https://www.filemail.com/d/exaqpvonhxooinv) with a dataset containing more than 20k float values and 30 features. I'm trying to convert it in a .npy file, which should have a shape of `(23706, 30)`. The problem is that when I load it through the function:

```
array_from_file = np.genfromtxt("machine-1-5.txt", dtype=str)
```

and I try to print its shape, I get a single array with all the values and a shape= `(23706,)`

How can I load it keeping its original shape? I don't understand it I need to use another function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works,

```
a = np.loadtxt("machine-1-5.txt", dtype=str, delimiter=',')
```

```
print(a.shape)
(23706, 38)
```